# Bucle de repeticiones con Javascript (según respuestas HTTP)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mocha

Estoy intentando hacer un bucle de repeticiones, que se repita hasta que la respuesta sea HTTP 200. Si hay algún error con código HTTP 500 devolverá error y se reintentará si el código es HTTP 204 hasta un número finito de veces (o durante un tiempo)
Además dejar pasar un rato entre reintentos...(esto no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo)

Esto fue lo que intenté hasta el momento:

```
  submitFileRequest.set('authorization',submitFile.headers.Authorization)
    .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, data) {

    var cont = 0;
    var estado = data.status;

do {

          var getResultsAwsHeaders = signRequest(submitFileRequest, targetConfig.GET_RESULTS_PATH);

          submitFileRequest
            .set('authorization', getResultsAwsHeaders.headers.Authorization)
            .set('x-amz-date', getResultsAwsHeaders.headers['X-Amz-Date'])
            .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
            .expect(200)
            .expect(expectedJSON)
            .end(function(err, data2) {

              if (err) {
                if(expectedJSON === null) {

                  try {
                    fs.writeFileSync(expectedJSONPath, JSON.stringify(data2.body, null, 2));
                    console.log('\n\nAVISO -> GUARDADO NUEVO JSON SIN TESTEAR EN ' + expectedJSONPath + '\n');
                    done();
                  }
                  catch(err) {
                    done(err);
                  }
                }
                else {
                  try {
                    compareJsonResults(expectedJSON, data2.body);
                    done();
                  }
                  catch(err) {
                    done(err);
                  }
                }
              }
              else {
                done();
              }
            });
            cont++;

        } while (estado != 200 || cont <= 10);
```

}

Me da errores y además la estructura no sé si es correcta, a ver si alguien me puede revisar. Os escribo aquí el error:

```
Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent
(node:13970) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 response listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Estoy usando nodejs, javascript y este código es para pasar unos test unitarios (con supertest y mocha). Gracias